# Protocol error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Target closed when using getText()

Tags: webdriver-io

Is anyone receiving the "Protocol error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Target closed" when trying to utilize getText()?

Code Snippet:
xpath = "//ag-grid-angular[contains(@class, 'rotnSearchSummaryGrid')]//div[@role='rowgroup']//div[@row-index="0"]//div[@col-id='rotationBaseCityCode']";
UI = await $(xpath).getText();